# UITableviewcell with Right Detail - TextLabel.text is always NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

It's just very basic thing, I am using UITableview with cell style "Right Detail"

Now, in method *cellForRowAtIndexPath* when I do

```
cell.textLabel.text         = @"Notification";
cell.detailTextLabel.text   = @"Dates";
```

It never takes the text neither displays on the screen. When I log the cell text like

```
NSLog(@"%@   --   %@",cell.textLabel.text, cell.detailTextLabel.text);
```

It prints the following line in console

```
(null)   --   (null)
```

Here are some more details:

Xcode Version: 8.3.1

Simulator: iPad Pro (12.9 inch) iOS 10.3

Storyboard based tableview
Already selected "Right Detail" option from Style option.
Already tested the following

```
[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:identifier]
```

On the requests, here is the complete code for "CellForRowAtIndexpath"

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell   = nil;
    if (tableView == self.tableviewBusinessSettings) {
        NSString *identifier    = @"BCell";
        cell   = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];\
        NSDictionary *dictSetting   = [self.arrayBusinessSettings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.textLabel setText:[dictSetting objectForKey:@"key"]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[dictSetting objectForKey:@"value"]];
    }else if (tableView == self.tableviewNotifications) {

        NSString *identifier    = @"NCell";
        cell   = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
        cell.textLabel.text         = @"Notification";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text   = @"Dates";
    }

    NSLog(@"%@   --   %@",cell.textLabel.text, cell.detailTextLabel.text);

    return cell;
}
```

Need quick help.

Thanks

Comment: `cell` is null ? `cell.textLabel` is null? `cell.detailTextLabel` is null? Could you show your whole `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code? Did you dequeue correctly the cell ?

Comment: Please show your full **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method so that we can understand your problem. Thanks

Comment: Neither cell is null nor the cell.textLabel, let me show the complete cell for row at index

Comment: Question is updated with code

Comment: Have you confirmed that either of your `if (tableView == ..` blocks are executing? Set a debug breakpoint and step through to make sure.

Comment: Yes, it calls for both sections one by one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking the data in dictionary Like before sending it to cells of tableView just nslog() the data you are sending and other Thing try using

```
cell.textlabel.text = [dictSetting objectForKey:@"key"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dictSetting objectForKey:@"value"];
```

and try replacing

```
 UITableViewCell *cell   = nil; to  UITableViewCell *cell;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer